# Arduino HTTP connection Issues - API is returning HTTP Response -1

Tags: c++, httpclient, arduino-esp32

My project involves reading an RFID tag, searching for the `UID` in my member list via a `GET` request, then passing the corresponding `memberID` to the next function. The next function sets various parameters via a `POST` request using the previously passed `memberID`.

The function to search for the `UID` and pass the `memberID` is working fine, but the next function refuses to connect to the server (HTTP response -1). However, if I call the second function first, it can establish a connection (HTTP response 201).

Here's my code snippet:

```cpp
String generateBearerToken() {
  Serial.println("Generating Bearer token...");
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected. Cannot generate token.");
    return "";
  }
 
  HTTPClient http;
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure();
  http.begin(client, TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
  http.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 
  String payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + String(clientSecretId) + "&client_secret=" + String(clientSecret);
 
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);
 
  String accessToken = "";
  if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    String response = http.getString();
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
    deserializeJson(doc, response);
    accessToken = doc["access_token"].as<String>();
    Serial.println("Bearer token generated successfully.");
    Serial.println(accessToken);
  } else {
    Serial.print("Failed to generate Bearer token. Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.println(http.getString());
  }
 
  http.end();
  return accessToken;
}
 
void sendGetMember(String bearerToken, String uid) {
  Serial.println("Sending GET Member...");
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected. Cannot send GET Member.");
    return; 
  }
 
  HTTPClient http;
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure();
  http.begin(client, MEMBER_ENDPOINT);
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
 
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
 
  if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println("GET Member successful");
    Serial.println("Member:");
    Serial.println(response);
 
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(4096);
    deserializeJson(doc, response);
 
    JsonArray members = doc["value"];
    for (JsonObject member : members) {
      String memberId = member["id"];
      String memberCode = member["code"];
      if (memberCode == uid) {
        Serial.println("Matching member found:");
        Serial.println("Member ID: " + memberId);
        sendPOST_Zeitwert(bearerToken, memberId);
        return;
      }
    }
    Serial.println("No matching member found for UID: " + uid);
  } else {
    Serial.print("Failed to send GET Member. Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.println(http.getString());
  }
 
  http.end();
}
 
void sendPOST_Zeitwert(String bearerToken, String memberId) {
  Serial.println("Sending POST Zeitwert...");
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected. Cannot send POST Zeitwert.");
    return;
  }
 
  HTTPClient http;
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure();
  http.begin(client, POST_Zeitwert);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
 
 
  DynamicJsonDocument payload(256);
  //payload["id"] = uid;
  payload["personId"] = "2c502f6a-b0ee-467f-be59-93693b828e5a";
  payload["type"] = "In";
  payload["clientType"] = "Web";
  String jsonString;
  
  serializeJson(payload, jsonString);
 
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(jsonString);
 
  Serial.print("HTTP Response Code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  Serial.println(http.getString());
 
  if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    Serial.println("POST_Zeitwert sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Failed to send POST_Zeitwert. Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.println(http.getString());
  }
 
  http.end();
}
 
void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastNTPUpdate > NTP_UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
    timeClient.update();
    lastNTPUpdate = millis();
  }
 
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    if (rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);
      Serial.print("RFID/NFC Tag Type: ");
      Serial.println(rfid.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
 
      Serial.print("UID:");
      String uid = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
        uid += (rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        uid += String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
      }
      Serial.println(uid);
 
      rfid.PICC_HaltA();
      rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
 
      String bearerToken = generateBearerToken();
      if (!bearerToken.isEmpty()) {
        sendGetMember(bearerToken, uid);
      }
    }
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I tried swapping the order of `sendGetMember` and `SendPost_TimeValue`. Now `sendGetMember` is getting an HTTP response of -1.

I also tried to send the second request as an HTTP request. Now the HTTP response Code is 400:

> "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port".